# Implement Authentication using ASP Identity With 2 Tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

Instead of the default 5 tables, I would like to use just **UserLoginsTable** and **UserTable**. Because I just have one 'User' type (Admin) and there's no point of having the other tables.

I'm using ASP MVC 5 framework and Entity Framework 6 (**Code First** approach).

How can I achieve this in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You create your own `User` inheriting `IdentityUser` like this:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{

}
```

Then you ignore the other classes in your `DbContext`, including the original `IdentityUser`, including your Users `DbSet`:

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // avoid some base class sets...

        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUser>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserRole>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityRole>();
        modelBuilder.Ignore<IdentityUserClaim>();

        // keep identity's original configurations for AspNetUsers and AspNetUserLogins
        EntityTypeConfiguration<User> configuration = modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("AspNetUsers");
        configuration.HasMany<IdentityUserLogin>(u => u.Logins).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId);
        IndexAttribute indexAttribute = new IndexAttribute("UserNameIndex")
        {
            IsUnique = true
        };
        configuration.Property((Expression<Func<User, string>>)(u => u.UserName)).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(0x100).HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(indexAttribute));
        configuration.Property((Expression<Func<User, string>>)(u => u.Email)).HasMaxLength(0x100);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(l => new { LoginProvider = l.LoginProvider, ProviderKey = l.ProviderKey, UserId = l.UserId }).ToTable("AspNetUserLogins");

    }

}
```

---

The reason why I ignored the original `IdentityUser` and created my own `User` is because of this exception:

> The navigation property 'Roles' is not a declared property on type
>   'IdentityUser'. Verify that it has not been explicitly excluded from
>   the model and that it is a valid navigation property.

I tried using `modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().Ignore(u => u.Roles);` but it didn't solve, though if someone knows how to solve this, we could keep things simpler, I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

when you run add-migration "ApplicationDbContext", its give you the code of migration file which contains all the queries, what you need here is write the code to delete other 4 tables like:

```
enable-migrations
add-migration "drop tables" //selected specific context
```

write down the below code inside the migration code class

```
DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserClaims");
DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserLogins");
DropTable("dbo.AspNetUserRoles");
DropTable("dbo.AspNetRoles");
```

finally run the below command

```
update-database
```

Comment: This won't work for automatic migrations, though is a simple solution. Just take note OP **do** want `AspNetUserLogins`.